# Как выйти в интернет по определенному интернет-соединению, если имеется несколько интернет-соединений?

Tags: c#, linux, windows

**Имеется:** комп (windows/linux на выбор) с несколькими usb входами, в каждом по usb/sim модему. Соответственно, единовременно на компе имеется несколько интернет-соединений.

**Вопрос:** как выйти в интернет программе на C# по определенному интернет-соединению. При этом, другие программы, которые используют другие интернет-соединения не должны лишиться доступа к интернету.

**Несколько виртуалок:** создать несколько виртуалок, в каждую завести по 1 интернет-соединению, и в каждой запускать необходимый софт - **не подходит**. Ибо периодически, необходимо выйти в интернет с другого интернет-соединения...

**В какую сторону копать, что почитать?**

Comment: К `C#` это не имеет ни малейшего отношения. Доступ к интернету контролируется и управляется сетевой подсистемой ОС.

Comment: @Bulson решение?

Comment: Например, в линуксе можно с помощью файервола перенаправлять запросы к определенным портам и(или) к определенным адресам на нужные сетевые интерфейсы. Как конкретно это сделать читайте документацию по настройке файервола.

Comment: @Bulson как вариант, спасибо!

Comment: Для linux гуглить ip netns. Например https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210992/61540

Comment: @AlexeyTen как вариант, спасибо!

Comment: @Bulson вообще то имеет. В конструктор TcpClient можно отдать локальный адрес, с которого нужно открыть соединение, тем самым выбрав интерфейс, без дополнительной возни с роутингом

Comment: @PashaPash, но ответы почему-то ориентированы именно на операционную систему, да ещё и только одну из указанных автором вопроса (то, что вопрос слишком широко задан, это, конечно, отдельная проблема).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin когда у тебя в руках есть только молоток, тогда все вокруг превращается в гвозди :) Написал C#-specific ответ, который применим под обе платформы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В C# (и не только в C#) можно явно указать локальный ip/интерфейс, с которого будут открываться соедниения, и тем самым, выбрать конкретное подключение.

Способ указания зависит от используемого варианта работы с сетью.

При работе через `TCPClient` можно [явно передать local endpoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient__ctor_System_Net_IPEndPoint_) в констуктор:

```
//Creates a TCPClient using a local end point.
IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry (Dns.GetHostName ()).AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ipLocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 0);
TcpClient tcpClientA = new TcpClient (ipLocalEndPoint);
```

При работе через `HttpWebRequest` [можно выбрать исходящий адрес в коллбеэке `SericePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate`]:

```
var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/");

req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = (servicePoint, remoteEndPoint, retryCount) =>
    new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(localIP), 0);
```

При работе через `WebClient` можно переопределить `GetWebRequest`, сведя выбор к решению для `WebRequest`:

```
class CustomWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);

        req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = (servicePoint, remoteEndPoint, retryCount) =>
            new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(localIP), 0);

        return req;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не решает проблемы с трафиком через шлюз. Надо добавить сорс роутинг к этому ответу.

Comment: @eri не совсем понимаю, о чем вы - у топикастера несколько физических модемов, у каждого прописан свой шлюз. Все автоматом пойдет через тот, который соответствует выбранному IP.

Comment: всё пойдет в шлюз с наименьшей метрикой не зависимо от сорса

Comment: @eri только что проверил локально, отправил с указанием интерфейса, для которого шлюз не прописан - не идет.

Comment: @eri заморочился, подключил USB модем (iPhone), получил два ethernet соединения. в ipconfig у обоих прописан default gateway. Дернул https://api.ipify.org/ кодом из ответа. При указании IP модема - выдает внешний адрес модема. При указании IP обычной сетевой карты - выдает внешний адрес офиса.

Comment: не силен в маршрутизации на виндовс - если все завелось, то ок. на линукс надо   добавить руль..

Comment: @PashaPash
>с которого будут открываться соедниения, и тем самым, выбрать конкретное подключение

Подскажите, соединение будет открыто именно для вызывающего его приложения? Если 5 одинаковых приложений / 5 модемов, и каждое приложение выйдет в инет именно со своего модема, то могут ли возникнуть какие либо конфликты (например, одно приложение откроет свое соединение и тем самым изменит уже ранее открытое другое соединение другого приложения)?

Comment: @Mike_Ro нет, не будет никаких конфликтов, это полностью независимые соединения

Answer (score 2):

Для начала каджому модему надо задать свой адрес, для примера 192.168.4.1.

Потом добавим маршрутизацию по метке - метка 4 отправляется в таблицу 4:

```
ip route add table 4 default via 192.168.4.1
ip rule add fwmark 4 table 4
```

Теперь поставим метку программе по группе процессов (Главная + подпроцессы). Группу процессов можно найти например так:

```
SID=`ps -eo sid,args |grep имяпрограммы |head -n 1 |cut -b 1-5`
```

И установка метки:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p TCP -m owner --sid-owner $SID -j MARK --set-mark 4
```

Теперь всё что вышло из этой программы уйдет в 192.168.4.1.

И пара правил чтоб пофиксить ресолвер:

```
ip rule add to 192.168.0.0/16 table main
```

Comment: Выбранный интерфейс зависит от исходного адреса, и по умолчанию ваш огород не нужен, даже на Linux.

Comment: этот огород нужен в первую очередь если нет доступа или желания править исходники. если будет не лень я задам новый вопрос по исходящей маршрутизации в линукс.

Answer (score 1):

Для примера интерфейс модема eth1. Создаем неймспейс TESTA, переносим туда модем, поднимаем сеть:

```
# ip netns add TESTA
# ip link set dev eth1 netns TESTA
# ip netns exec TESTA ip link set dev eth1 up
# ip netns exec TESTA dhcpcd eth1
```

Из основной системы интерфейс пропадет. Также подпортится resolv.conf, исправим на внешний:

```
# echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf
```

И можно запускать программу в собственной сети:

```
$ xhost +
$ sudo ip netns exec TESTA su eri -c "DISPLAY=$(DISPLAY) opera --user-data-dir=/home/eri/.opera_TESTA/"
```

Comment: Облака головного мозга. Давайте ещё докер во все дырочки запинаем.

Comment: я этот способ использую для тестирования хотспота.)